# Name for a work attitude

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a name for a work attitude that can be described as the person treating their job as something of their own. To take some examples, they treat every single project or piece of work almost as if it was their own children, like something they will be identified with say long after their death; they try to save money as much as possible on business trips even if the expenses would be paid by the company in full regardless of the amount; they don't terrorize the bathroom or other public spaces. Let me add that the concept is very close to "wholehearted, passionate, earnest" etc.; but these words miss the "feel like my own" component.

Comment: I hate bathroom terrorists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My answer is peppered throughout your question: *owning* the job.

Here is an example:
http://www.businessweek.com/careers/content/dec2004/ca20041222_0814_ca010.htm

Comment: Sounds good. As a more general term, "work ethos" could be used.